# Primary Key + Foreign Key with Duplicate Entry error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have two models which are related to each other:

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="permissions") */
class Permissions {
    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue @Column(type="integer")
     * @var integer
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    public function getId() { return $this->id; }

    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }
}
```

and

```
/** @Entity @Table(name="permissions_types") */
class PermissionsTypes {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Permissions")
     * @JoinColumn(name="perm_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $perm;

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $name;

    public function setType($type) { $this->type = $type; }
    public function getType() { return $this->type; }

    public function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }
    public function getName() { return $this->name; }
}
```

When I want to add to PermissionsTypes two entities with values:

```
perm | type | name
-------------------
  1  |   0  | test1
  1  |   1  | test2
```

I get

> Duplicate entry '1' for key 'UNIQ_12CF91AFFA6311EF'

error on the 1st column. What I do wrong?

Comment: Can you do a `show create table table_name` for the PermissionsTypes table? Looks like you have a unique key on just the perm column, when it should be across perm and type.

Comment: Yeah, I have Unique Key on this column. The question is, how it's creating?

Comment: How did you create the table schema? By hand, or was it auto-generated somehow?

Comment: @DigitalPrecision Doctrine is an ORM and is most likely the tool used to generate the schema

Comment: @Phil: Yes I know. I'm trying to figure out if the schema file has the unique constraint, or the actual table itself. In order for the schema file to be generated, the table has to exist. If he has a unique constraint on only the perm column, it will limit the tables ability to act as a pivot table between M:M relationship between permissions and types. Guess it doesn't matter, he accepted answer so provided solution must have worked.

Comment: @DigitalPrecision Table schema was created with the help of this command: `doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force`. you have all described in http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html#generating-the-database-schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems here...

1. You can't use a related entity as another entity's primary key (`@Id`)
2. You're using a *one-to-one* relationship but want to add more than one `PermissionTypes` per `Permissions`. This requires a *one-to-many* association, preferably bi-directional.

Add types to `Permissions` with

```
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="PermissionTypes", mappedBy="perm")
 */
protected $types;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->types = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    // see http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html#collections
}
```

and change `PermissionTypes` to

```
class PermissionsTypes {

    /**
     * @Id @GeneratedValue
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Permissions", inversedBy="types")
     * @JoinColumn(name="perm_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $perm;
```

You should read the [Association Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html) section of the manual carefully.

Comment: 1. I dont understand it. Could You explain it more precisely? 2. I changed "one-to-one" to "manny-to-one" and it worked :).

Comment: Have an error: [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
[Syntax Error] Expected Doctrine\Common\Annotations\DocLexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got 'mappedBy' at position 43 in property Permissions::$types.

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos I missed some commas in the annotation mapping, see my updated answer

Comment: Your #1 point is incorrect. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity please revise your answer since I'm having a similar problem and the Doctrine Documentation clearly says you can.